# Synchronize transition across multiple control instances

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have several custom control.  One of the requirements is to have the control be able to flash based on it's state.  I am using a fade transition, which works great.

How can I sync the fade transition so that if multiple controls are flashing on the screen, they are fading in and out at the same rate?

The only thing I can think of to make this work easily is to have a static ParallelTransition that each instance adds it's fade transition to when active but that just doesn't sound like a clean approach to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use binding link everything to a key value which changes based upon a timeline.

The following code will create a bunch of circles, then fire off blinking on them at various times, but once the blinking starts, all of the circles continue blinking in unison (don't run this if you are prone to epilepsy...)

You can play around with the values and the interpolators used in the timeline to get the effect you want.

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Random;

public class Synchronicity extends Application {
    private static final double N = 10;
    private static final double R = 10;
    private static final Duration D = Duration.seconds(2);

    private static final double MIN_VAL = 0.1;
    private static final double MAX_VAL = 1;

    private static final Random r = new Random();

    private final DoubleProperty opacity = new SimpleDoubleProperty(MAX_VAL);
    private final Timeline oscillator = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, MAX_VAL, Interpolator.EASE_BOTH)),
            new KeyFrame(D.divide(2), new KeyValue(opacity, MIN_VAL, Interpolator.EASE_BOTH))
    );

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        Pane layout = new Pane();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Circle circle = new Circle(R, Color.FIREBRICK);
            circle.setCenterX(2 * R + i * R * 3);
            circle.setCenterY(R * 2);
            layout.getChildren().add(circle);

            PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(D.multiply(r.nextDouble() * N));
            pause.setOnFinished(e ->  blink(circle));
            pause.play();
        }
        layout.setMinSize(R + N * R * 3,R * 4);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();

        oscillator.setAutoReverse(true);
        oscillator.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        oscillator.play();
    }

    private void blink(Node node) {
        node.opacityProperty().bind(opacity);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the sort of solution I was looking for!